# Quarkus Micrometer one Counter with different tag keys will not work

Tags: quarkus, micrometer

I am trying to register a counter that I would like to reuse in my code, using different Tags to highlight different states, where/if needed.
This seems to not work, even though I can't seem to find any documentation pointing to it being restricted / not supported.

My counters would look like so:

```
@ApplicationScoped
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class MetricsService {   

    private final Counter.Builder userRequestCounter = Counter.builder("incomming_user_request");
    private final Counter.Builder userResponseCounter = Counter.builder("incomming_user_response");
    
        public void incrementRequestStart() {
            userRequestCounter.tags("state", "started").register(registry).increment();
    }
    
        public void incrementRequestDone(String statusCode) {
            userRequestCounter.tags("state", "done", "statusCode", statusCode).register(registry).increment();
    }

        public void incrementRequestFailure(String errorCode) {
            userRequestCounter.tags("state", "failure", "errorCode", errorCode).register(registry).increment();
    }
}
```

Tried to also register one directly and incrementing it:

`registry.counter("incomming_user_request", ..tags)`

It also did not work.

Even though my code is calling two methods, I am getting one entry in the metrics endpoint. My code is calling the "success" one as well before finishing the work:

> TYPE incomming_user_request counter
> HELP incomming_user_request
> incomming_user_request_total{state="started"} 1.0

Tried registering the counter using Counter.builder, tried registering one directly and incrementing it, as described above.
The expected behaviour would be to have all entries:

> TYPE incomming_user_request counter
> HELP incomming_user_request
> incomming_user_request_total{state="started"} 2.0
> incomming_user_request_total{state="done", statusCode="OK"} 1.0
> incomming_user_request_total{state="failure", errorCode="500"} 1.0

Can what I'm trying to do even work? I am trying real hard to use a single counter name and not have different ones for different states of one method or controller.

Thanks!

Comment: A few thoughts: you should use `.` instead of `_` in your code, Micrometer will translate it to your registry (Prometheus). This comes very handy if you want to migrate to another registry or use multiple ones. If you want to count multiple things you need multiple counters, Bruno's answer is a good solution for dynamic tags and inlining counter, you might also want to look into a recent feature we added that can help you: https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/pull/4097

Comment: What you are trying to do (having different set of tags with the same name) is not just discouraged but it does not even work with the Prometheus client. If you add a tag, you should add it to every time series with the same name, in your case:
```
incomming_user_request_total{state="started", status="unknown"} 2.0
incomming_user_request_total{state="done", status="ok"} 1.0
incomming_user_request_total{state="failure", status="failed"} 1.0
```
But `status` is pretty redundant here. :)

Comment: So you can do:
```
incomming_user_request_total{state="started", status_code="0"} 2.0
incomming_user_request_total{state="done", status_code="200"} 1.0
incomming_user_request_total{state="failure", status_code="500"} 1.0```
But now `state` is kind of redundant since the `status_code` contains that information. :)

Comment: @JonatanIvanov this is just an example i'm playing with. The idea would be that I will have to be able to include any number of tags that are found to be relevant. 
This means that for some of the metrics I could have 1, for some under the same counter I could have 3.

Comment: Doing that is not possible with the Prometheus Java client and highly discouraged by the Prometheus server maintainers.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a counter directly from the registry. This will work:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class MetricsService {

    @Inject
    MeterRegistry registry;

    public void incrementRequestStart() {
        registry.counter("incomming_user_request", "state", "started").increment();
    }

    public void incrementRequestDone(String statusCode) {
        registry.counter("incomming_user_request", "state", "done", "statusCode", statusCode).increment();
    }

    public void incrementRequestFailure(String errorCode) {
        registry.counter("incomming_user_request", "state", "failure", "errorCode", errorCode).increment();
    }
}
```

For more details please check the related Quarkus Micrometer documentation: https://quarkus.io/guides/telemetry-micrometer#counters

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work, this was how the initial implementation looked like.
The only change from what you commented would be that I defined some final Strings for the tag keys.

Comment: I actually tested this code and it worked on my machine...
What Quarkus version are you in?

Comment: Tested it again, i am running exactly the same config as your example. The only changes are some constants for the counter name, state, etc.
If i am throwing an exception along the way in my code, i should get 2 entries, but i only get the first one:

incomming_user_request_total{state="started"} 
--I am missing the error one.

I am using Quarkus 3.7.1

Comment: It depends on how you are catching the exception, most likely, it is skipping the call of `incrementRequestFailure()`